# making Unix socket with ssl for Redis in nginx

Tags: sockets, ssl, nginx, redis, proxypass

I have nginx configuration, I changed the redis port to socket connection and now that unix socket is listening with some port 8888 and I configured it in nginx.

Now I want to make the connection (webpage to redis unix socket) secure with TLS.
Without ssl I able to get ping/pong  communication is successfully working but when I trying with ssl ( listen 8888 ssl) then ECONNRESET is happening.

When I add server_name it is saying directive is not acceptable here.

And the config structure is like this:

```
stream {
sys {
server unix:/var/run/tmp/redis.sock;
}
server{
listen 8888 ssl;
# server_name not accepting here
server_name abc.com;  <------------------->A
proxy_pass sys;
ssl_certificate                 /a/b/c; 
ssl_certificate_key             /aa/bb/cc;
ssl_trusted_certificate         /aaa/bbb/ccc;
ssl_protocols                   TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_handshake_timeout 30s;
ssl_ciphers                 'EC:AB:CC;
ssl_session_cache           shared:SSL:50m;
ssl_session_timeout         5m;
ssl_verify_depth  2;
}
}
http{
upstream api{
server 127.0.0.1:2222;
keepalive 32;
}
server{
listen 443 ssl;
server_name _;
location /{

}
}
}
```

Comment: Have you gotten around to fixing this? I am hitting the same issue.